# Wildcards in the exceptions to Thunderbird's remote content rules

Tags: email, thunderbird, wildcards, whitelist

I would like to prevent remote content to load by default, so I have not checked `Privacy -> Mail Content -> Allow remote content in messages`. To the right of that option, there is a button for `Exceptions` to this rule, allowing for whitelisting and blacklisting specific sites or email addresses.

I would like to whitelist all email addresses from my university, but could not find out a way to do this. I tried

```
*@university.ca
.*@university.ca
@university.ca
```

Is it possible to define wildcards for this setting? Or is there another way of blocking remote content in general, but allowing it for all addresses from my university?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Update 20170428

Actually, the whitelist mentioned below if for the domain where the images are loaded from, not the email address of the sender. There does not seem to be a way to achieve what I want in the current version of thunderbird. Related bug reports [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=542457#c1) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457296).

---

I got help to solve this over at the Mozillazine forum, which pointed me to [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Privacy_basics_-_Thunderbird#Advanced). I include the solution here for future reference:

> A better alternative would be to use the Config editor to create a mail.trusteddomains setting that specifies what e-mail domains it should automatically display remote images for. This is much easier than having to specify each email address, but you're taking the risk that you won't get any messages with a spoofed From: header in one of those domains. The setting contains a list of domains separated by commas, with no wild cards, white space or subdomains allowed. This change won't take effect until you restart Thunderbird.
>
> For example:
>
> mozillazine.org is okay
>
> mozilla.com,mozilla.org is okay
>
> *.mozilla.com is invalid
>
> mozilla.com, mozilla.org is invalid
>
> forums.mozillazine.org is invalid

Comment: This no longer works.